magick: resize image before put it to a frame
I am using magick to add frames around my pics.
I have a frame picture where I keep transparent the picture placeholder area inside the frame:

Then I wrote a simple bash script that loops on the files in my pic directory and generates the framed pics.
WORKSPACE_HOME="..."
INPUT_IMG_HOME="$WORKSPACE_HOME/input/original-pics"
FRAME_IMG="$WORKSPACE_HOME/input/dia-frame/transparent-dia-1.png"
OUTPUT_IMG_HOME="$WORKSPACE_HOME/output/with-frame"

rm -f "$OUTPUT_IMG_HOME"/*
INDEX=0
for INPUT_IMG in $INPUT_IMG_HOME/*; do
    if [ -f "$INPUT_IMG" ]; then
        INDEX=$(expr $INDEX + 1)
        INPUT_IMG_FILENAME=$(basename $INPUT_IMG)
        INPUT_IMG_NAME=${INPUT_IMG_FILENAME%.*}
        OUTPUT_IMG="$OUTPUT_IMG_HOME/$(printf '%05d' $INDEX)-$INPUT_IMG_NAME.png"
        printf "($INDEX) framing \"${INPUT_IMG}\" to \"$OUTPUT_IMG\"...\n"
        $WORKSPACE_HOME/bin/magick "$INPUT_IMG" "$FRAME_IMG" +swap -auto-orient -gravity center -compose DstOver -composite "$OUTPUT_IMG"
    fi
done

Everything works great, but unfortunately the size of my pics do not fit properly to the size of the frame (dia). My pics are sometimes bigger, sometimes smaller then the frame's inside area. This is more critical when the pic has portrait orientation or smaller then the frame. For example:
portrait orientation, original image must be reduced:

original image size must be increased:

Is that possible to instruct magick to resize the pics before put them to the frame?

I can't run your script itself, but barring aspect ratio weirdness, it seems to me you could just -resize.
    $WORKSPACE_HOME/bin/magick "$INPUT_IMG" -resize 2720x1550 "$FRAME_IMG" +swap -auto-orient -gravity center -compose DstOver -composite "$OUTPUT_IMG"

As you probably know, options are processed serially. So by resizing the image before your frame gets mentioned, you effectively change just that first input file without affecting the frame or the result.
The numbers I picked are approximately the space in your frame's transparent area, which is handily centered.  Adjust to suit.  If you tend to have wider images and would like to crop the sides to fill things vertically, just drop the first number, so:
-resize x1550

Is this the effect you're looking for?

Note that you can just affect one image although you have two - just use parentheses to ensure the -resize operator only affects one image. Here I only resize the second image magick image1.png \( image2.png -resize 600x400 \) ...

That was the key info and that was the reason why the -resize did not work for me as I expected: As you probably know, options are processed serially

You have two choices:

distort to fit
extend/pad to fit


If you want to distort an image to an exact size and disregard its aspect ratio, you need to use the ! operator to coerce ImageMagick into disregarding the aspect ratio. As the exclamation mark is a shell meta character in bash you will need to escape it with a slash. So, to force an image to exactly 640x480, use:
magick input.png -resize 640x480\! result.png

You can equally use:
magick input.png -resize '640x480!' result.png


If you want to make an entire image fit within a given window, or shape, you would resize it first and that will make the image fit on one dimension, then you would extend it with an "extent" to pad the other dimension.
So, if we start with these three images:
magick -size 400x400 gradient:yellow-cyan 400x400.png  # square 
magick -size 640x480 gradient:lime-blue 640x480.png    # wide, i.e. landscape
magick -size 400x400 gradient:red-lime  480x640.png    # tall, i.e. portrait




Here's how you can fit to 500x500 and extend whichever dimension is necessary. I have set the background colour to pink so you can see how to do that too. Note that I set the gravity to center so the image is padded equally all around. If you set it to North-West, the image will be placed in the top-left corner and the padding of the extent will be below and to the right of the image.
magick input.png -resize 500x500 -gravity center -background pink -extent 500x500 result.png




